# How can I use etoc package to customize toc with crammed sections?

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, etoc

How can I use `etoc` package to customize toc with **crammed sections** like the picture below?

By the way, can anybody please give a brief intro about `etoc` package? It seems very powerful for customizing toc, but the documentation on CTAN looks very complicated...

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `etoc`, you define the style of each sectional command (`\section` in this example) that will be included in the local table of contents.

`\etocsetstyle{<levelname>}{<start>}{<prefix>}{<contents of the entry>}{<finish>}`

For the main part, the content of the entry, you have available

`\etocnumber` number of the section (not used in this example)

`\etocname` title of the section

`\etocpage` page of the section

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage{etoc} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\etocsetnexttocdepth{section} %list up to and including section

\newcommand{\inlinetoc}{% produce the inline local table of contents
    \begingroup
    \etocsettocstyle{\vskip-2\baselineskip}{\vskip0.5\baselineskip} % etoc style for the local TOC
    \etocsetstyle{section}% level = section
    {\etocskipfirstprefix\sffamily}% code before.  (Do not use prefix for the first section}
    {\space}% prefix to contents of the entry (space)
    {\etocname{}~\textbf{\etocpage}\enspace}% content of the entry
    {}% after (nothing)
    \localtableofcontents % local ToC
    \endgroup
}


\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{The Market}
    
    \inlinetoc %local table of contents inline
    
    \section{Constructing a Model}
    \lipsum[4-8]
    \section{Optimization and Equilibrium}
    \lipsum[4-8]
    \section{The Demand Curve}
    \lipsum[4-8]
    \section{The Supply Curve}
    \lipsum[4-8]
    \section{Market Equilibrium}
    \lipsum[4-8]
    \section{Comparative Statics}
    \lipsum[4-8]
    \section{Other Ways to Allocate Apartments}
\end{document}
```

The package document includes many snippets to familiarize yourself with the possibilities. (Acrobat reader might be needed to extract the embed code in the document pdf)

Comment: Really appreciated your answer :)